# change the datetime format in flutter, to leave it only with the date

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to know how I can change the datetime format in flutter, to leave it only with the date.
I also want to know if there is another widget that only contains the date.

Thanks

Comment: Aside from `DateTime`widget ?

Comment: Why not check the docs? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets

Comment: What is the format that you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can use DateFormat from intl package.
With it you can custom to any format that you need.

Add to pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.15.7
```

On Dart code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final dateFormatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
final dateString = dateFormatter.format(DateTime.now());
```

Then you can put the string into any widget. Example:

```
Text(dateString)
```

About date format: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html

Answer (score 3):

Make a new DateTime and get the day from that:

```
var date = DateTime.now();
var result = "${date.year}/${date.month}/${date.day}";
print(result);  // prints 2019/3/6
```

Comment: Oh ok, thanks.

Another doubt
you can change the language to the flutter date time, since by default it is in English ...

Comment: Correct, for that you'd need the `intl` package mentioned by Long Phan

Answer (score 2):

You can get the day month and year from DateTime object and convert it to string.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.now();
print(today); // prints 2019-12-15 00:00:00.000
DatetTime date = DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day).toString().substring(0,10); 
print(date); // prints 2019-12-15
```

hope this helps

Comment: whats the right solution according to you ?by way can you tell me a case where this wont work?

Comment: what the point reset hours/mins/seconds if you wont use it later `DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day)`