# Flutter How to format the date and time pull from the database

Tags: mysql, flutter

Good day i want to format my date 2020-11-05 to 11-05-2020 my database type is timestamp

[![Here is my view ][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOgYN.jpg

//this is my my litsview

```
   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: getData,
          key: _refresh,
          child: loading
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    final x = list[i];
                    debugPrint(x.toString());
                    return ExpansionTile(
                      title: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                              'Transaction ID:\t' +
                                  x.transaction_id +
                                  '\nVesselname:\t' +
                                  x.vesselname +
                                  '\nVoyage #:\t' +
                                  x.voyageno,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                            title: Text('Ship Call #:\t' + x.scn,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))),
```

//here is my value anchorage estimated time of arrival i want to format it into 11-20-2020

```
  ListTile(
             

                        title: Text(
                        'Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n' + x.anchor_eta,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))),
          

                   ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                        'Anchor Actual Time of Arrival :\n' + x.anchor_ata,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))),
             
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
));
```

}
}

Comment: Use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Comment: but i pull my data from the database type is not a subtype of date and time and i have this result sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function for formatting your date

```
String formatDate(String dbDate){
  List<String> dateTimeList = dbDate.split(" ");
  List<String> dateList = dateTimeList.first.split("-");
  String dateTime = dateList[1]+"-"+dateList.last+"-"+dateList.first + " "+ dateTimeList.last;
  return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: but i have a date and time here sir it display the date but time wont

Comment: from formatDate function simply return date + " "+ dbDate.split(" ").last; instate of date.

Comment: String formatDate(String dbDate) {
  List<String> dateList = dbDate.split(" ").first.split("-");
  String date = dateList[1] +
      "-" +
      dateList.last +
      "-" +
      dateList.first +
      " " +
      dbDate.split(" ");
  return date;
} like this sir?

Comment: what website more about split and formatiting sir i got it

Answer (score 0):

Hi flutter run(cool name btw),

There are two ways you can do achieve this:

1. Use intl [library](https://pub.dev/packages/intl):

```dart
String correctlyFormattedDateTime(DateTime date){
   return DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(date); //=> 02/07/2020
}
```

2. Edit the date directly:

```dart
String correctlyFormattedDateTime(DateTime date){
   return '${date.day}/${date.month}/${date.year}'; //=> 02/07/2020
}
```

Here is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023657/change-the-datetime-format-in-flutter-to-leave-it-only-with-the-date)

Please leave a comment if you need any further help!

Comment: title: Text(
                        'Anchor Estima Time of Arrival :\n' + x.anchor_eta,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0))), how do i put it in this code sir?

Comment: You simply create a file for example: "date_formatter.dart" and in this file you add one of the functions above inside. Next you want to wrap your "x.anchor_eta" in the correctlyFormattedDateTime like so: correctlyFormattedDateTime(x.anchor_eta)  or even before this if you like. But just a note, your date must be in the DateTime format other wise the function won't work. If it is not in the DateTime format, just search on the internet on how to convert it. Lastly, if the answer above is correct, please mark it so future people be know it has fixed your problem. Hope that helps!

Comment: the output is 2020-11-6 10:29

Comment: Is that from your database or after you have user the function?

Comment: i tried your suggestion and it display like that in to my app

Comment: type is not a subtype of date and time

Comment: Yeah like I said, because you are querying it from a database it won't most likely be in the form of Date Time. So you need to google how to convert the TimeStamp form of the date from you SQL Database into a Date Time and then the function should work.